# Convert camelcase to lower and underscore_case using bash commands

Tags: bash

I am trying to convert camelcase string into lower and underscore case, I don't know many bash commands and I couldn't find anything, if this doesn't take big time for you, please give me example. like: 'TestCamelCase' -> result should be 'test_camel_case'. thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/^[[:upper:]]/\L&/;s/[[:upper:]]/\L_&/g' <<< 'TestCamelCase'
test_camel_case
```

`\L` is a [`GNU sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) extension that turns the replacement to lowercase.

Comment: yes it works, thanks. one more question if you don't mind. can I save this result in variable? and how? thanks you!

Comment: You need to use command substitution to do that: `variable=$(sed ...)`.

Comment: ok but then when I write 'echo var', it prints out 'var', I don't know almost anything about bush commands and sorry to bug you...

Comment: I recommend you read some beginner tutorial :) You need to use variable expansion: `echo "$variable"`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an approach that avoids the need for GNU sed extensions and works on macOS:

```
$ echo 'TestCamelCase' | sed 's/[[:upper:]]/_&/g;s/^_//' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
test_camel_case
```